# Integrate regular google instead of CSE?

Tags: html, google-custom-search

I know what I am doing is quite dumb, but is there anyway to do a regular google search instead of a custom google search(don't like it because when I search Define Happy, it doesn't give u the dictionary thing). I just want it so that I can essentially have my own homepage rather than google's.

Comment: What have you tried?  What *exactly* are you after? Code? A complete example?

Comment: Like any alternative google apis or other search engines?